# Should unnecessary elses be kept?

Tags: java, coding-style

If i have a simple chunk of code like:

```
public void tracePath(){
   int steps = 0;
   steps = bfs();       
   if(steps==0){
      pathFound(false);
      System.exit(0);
   }else{
      System.out.println(steps);
      pathFound(true);
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

AFAIK this could be rewriten without the *else* as

```
public void tracePath(){
   int steps = 0;
   steps = bfs();       
   if(steps==0){
      pathFound(false);
      System.exit(0);
   }
   System.out.println(steps);
   pathFound(true);
   System.exit(0);
}
```

Is there a performance (or other logical) reason so keep (or lose) the *else*? or is it just (in this example) stylistic choice?

Comment: Why even bother setting :

pathFound(false)

when steps == 0

given that you are going to exit?  This just seems like a giant code smell.

Comment: this was just a junky bit of code i was using while debuging something when that question came to me.
the exit was only there as i wasnt interested in execution part that point at the time/

Comment: when the exit is not present, your two examples are not equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is stylistic preference because you exit at the end of the if statement.  If you did not have a system.exit(0) at the end of the if, in the second example you would execute both pieces of code.

Answer (score 1):

I would change it to this:

```
public void tracePath(){
int steps = 0;
steps = bfs();       
pathFound((!(steps==0)));

System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change it slightly, to this:

```
public void tracePath(){
   int steps = 0;
   steps = bfs();       
   if(steps==0){
      pathFound(false);
   }else{
      System.out.println(steps);
      pathFound(true);
   }
   System.exit(0);
}
```

Although, honestly, calling `System.exit` from a function called `tracePath` seems a bit extreme in the first place.